# Difference between using Intellij modules and Python packages within project

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I have an Intellij project that contains 3 different components to it, all written in Python. I want to import .py files between the three components, but this only seems to work when the components are set up as directories rather than Intellij modules. Not pictured, but I did add __init__.py files to each of the module directories (foo, bar, baz) and no luck.

Import using modules: https://i.stack.imgur.com/emOMf.jpg

Import using packages: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1fgK.jpg

Why don't imports seem to work for Python modules? Are they even necessary for Python projects?

Comment: Why don't you use PyCharm? The CE (Community Edition) is fully functional. And it's by JetBrains like IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: I use Pycharm at home. Unfortunately at work the only option is IntelliJ.

Answer (score 4):

Have you configured module dependencies? Please see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies.

If it does not help, please provide an example of a project structure and steps to reproduce. (For your convenience, feel free to open a ticket on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY).